# Options Menu on Spinner

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a way to add items to a spinner from within the spinner item list dialog.

Ideally, I could hit the menu button and select an option to add, prompt the user with an edittext dialog and update the item list. Is there a way to make the options menu accessible on a dialog?

I thought I might need to create an activity but then how do I make it look like a spinner item list dialog and how would I get it to show up when the spinner is clicked?

All I'm trying to do is add an unobtrusive way to launch a prompt to add items to the spinner item list from within the dialog. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about allowing them to long-click the list and handling the long click event?

`Spinner s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourspinner);
s.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){}...`

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ArrayList<String> array_spinner;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
    array_spinner=new ArrayList<String>();
    array_spinner.add("value");
    array_spinner.add("value 2");
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

    s.setLongClickable(true);
    s.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            array_spinner.add("value 3");

            return false;

        }}
    );
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think spinner's support that. Which brings up another issue, deleting items from the spinner. I had planned on using an ItemLongClickListener to show/hide a delete button next to the item. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: actually you can - but perhaps not the way you think.. You can't while the spinner selector list is visible, but you can add it to the base spinner (the view itself that has the dropdown arrow).

Comment: You might be better off designing a custom dialog or activity that pops up with a listview inside that you use like a spinner.  You'd have a lot more flexibility.